# How to see html sourcecode of a web page in Win8 IE10

Tags: operating-system, internet-explorer-10

I want to see html source code in IE10  Browser in Win8 OS.

As we all know in win7 IE , by right clicking on the page and if clicking on view source ,

we can view the source code of a page.

But can you help me how to see the html source code  of a page in IE10 and Win8 OS.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Same thing, but open the page on the desktop if you haven't already.

Comment: @ Rowland Shaw : I have opened a web page in Win8 IE10 Browser. When i right click on the page , i am getting the web page image in a rectangle window in the top of the  web page. But i am struggling to find the view source of a  page.

Comment: Got it now , i opened the page through the desktop.Thanks Rowlandshaw.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spanner icon, and choose "View on the desktop", and view source/use developer tools on there...

[image]